# systemd takes lots of time to kill containerized service

Tags: docker, systemd

I'm running a python application in a containerized environment and created a service file which will start and stop this application (under centos)

The service file that I'm using should send NOHUP signal to the container and kill it immediately

```
Description=py Container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=always
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker exec %n stop
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm %n
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name %n -t=false -i -e environment=env1 container_name
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker kill --signal=SIGHUP %n
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/docker rm -f %n

[Install]
WantedBy=local.target
```

Systemd should stop the container and remove it in a timely manner, but it takes up tp 2 minutes to kill it. 
Could you advise on how to accelerate the termination of the container ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because questions about the Linux operating system and its utilities should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

if that signal `SIGHUP` is not so important for you , you may try to `kill` the `contaier` without it `/usr/bin/docker kill %n` or simply trying to stop it using `/usr/bin/docker stop %n`